# Action Script 3 - Full screen from class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, package, fullscreen

please note that I am a novice when it comes to Actionscript 3 and lot of what I could do with reasonable competency in AS2 I now can't in AS3, to my frustration! OK, I'm fleshing out a simple drag drop and decorate application in Flash. I'm wanting to use the external action script class/package to allow for it full screen from my desktop and I'm in a tangle, with constructor errors being thrown up and all sorts. Could anyone give any pointers?

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.display.Stage;
        import flash.display.StageDisplayState;

    public class fullmode extends MovieClip {
         public function fullmode() {
             fullbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullScreen); 
         }// btn declared - - - - - - - - 

         //public function fullmode(event:MouseEvent):void {
         stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
         }

    }




     //--------------------- drag item
     public class DragDrop extends MovieClip {
         public function DragDrop() {
            dragme.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
            dragme.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
        }

        private function mouseDownHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {
            var obj = evt.target;
            obj.startDrag();
         }
         private function mouseUpHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {
            var obj = evt.target;
             obj.stopDrag();
        }
    }
 }
```

Thanks world!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few syntax errors/typos, I've fixed them below:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;

    public class Fullmode extends MovieClip 
    {
        public function Fullmode() 
        {
            fullbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullScreen); 
        }

        private function fullScreen(event:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
        }
    }
}
```

Standard practice dictates that your class names should be capitalized, hence `Fullmode` instead of `fullmode`.

Additionally, you had named your `MouseEvent.CLICK` listener the same as your class, instead of what you intended to name it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm pretty slow with AS3 Still... it goes months on end between me using it. Really appreciate your help.